# How to set height of the UWP Toolkit DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, datagridrow

Using this MSDN tip I try to set height of the UWP Toolkit DataGrid row but no success.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/sizing_options

> Sizing Rows and Row Headers DataGrid Rows By default, a DataGrid row's
> Height property is set to Double.NaN ("Auto" in XAML), and the row
> height will expand to the size of its contents. The height of all rows
> in the DataGrid can be specified by setting the DataGrid.RowHeight
> property. Users cannot change the row height by dragging the row
> header dividers.

I have tried folowing

1. `RowHeight="12" of the DataGrid`
2. `DataGridTemplateColumn -> TextBlock Height="12"`

Nothing works.

**XAML**

```
 <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind TripEvents, Mode=OneWay}"
                   x:Name="dataGridTripEvents"
                   HeadersVisibility="Column"
                   SelectionMode="Single"  
                   GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"   
                   RowHeight="12">
  <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>             
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#">
       <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Height="12" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding NumberByOrder, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2,2,2,2" Padding="2,2,2,2">
             </TextBlock>
          </DataTemplate>                                                
       </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Setting the `RowHeight` property should work. What if you set it to for example `100`? Do you see any difference?

Comment: Please check source code [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L447), the min height is 32, if value you set less than 32, it will not effect.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It seems you are right, bro.... Well... Type the asnwer I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @mm8   Yeah it works for 100 pixels but  @Zhu said it seems imposible to make rowheight less then 32 pixels  `  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>`  I assume it is done for minimum finger touch space. But if you have other solution please share with us. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check source code [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L447), the min height is 32, if value you set less than 32, it will not effect.

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource DataGridCellBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
```